# Reversing order of divs depending on width

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a menu consisting of two parts (see image). On mobile, I'd like to show these menu items stacked from top to bottom, but starting with the bottom menu and ending with the top menu. Is there any (clean) way to do this with CSS or will I have to create two menus and show the correct one depending on page width?

EDIT: To clarify, the image is just to show an example of what I mean. I'm wondering in a more general sense if it's possible to somehow reverse the divs in CSS (without absolute positioning etc).

EDIT 2: Apologies for not adding any code. Here's a small pen that shows the situation: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWwrMW

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="nav__top">
    <li>Sub Item 1</li>
    <li>Sub Item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav__primary">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>


.nav__top,
.nav__primary {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  text-align: right;
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
}
```

On mobile, I want the sub items to be displayed underneath the main items.

[image: menu]

Comment: 1. Include enough code here to see your markup and basic css 2. Include the expected output for both

Comment: @DaniP, okay will do

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: Have no time right now to write a proper answer but you can ues flexbox and order to change on mobile https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpJdmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `flex` and `flex-direction: column-reverse`, or for more control, using the `order` property on flex children. But with your example, `flex-direction: column-reverse` would work.

```css
.nav__top li,
.nav__primary li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .nav li {
    display: list-item;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="nav__top">
    <li>Sub Item 1</li>
    <li>Sub Item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav__primary">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I literally just figured this out myself as well haha.

Answer (score 1):

This added CSS will reverse the order in the second menu:

```
.nav__primary {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

You can put it in a media query.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryQjdg

ADDITION: I overread the wish of it to be stacked horizontally. In this case you need

```
.nav__primary {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want responsive nav bar you have to use media queries. Something like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}}
```

This will work if your menu was built by list.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Since I only need to support mobile browsers I can use Flexbox:

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```